# Assign a static style to each rendered component only once

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, rendering

Is there a way that I can apply my style to each individual card image only once.  For example, I am assigning a transform style to css via a function; I expect the image to hold on to that original value, but when a new component is rendered that card should have a different transform value applied, but the original existing component style should not be re-rendered.  Currently all transform styles are being re-rendered with different values, is this possible in a functional component in react? Depending on where I place my current variable inside Card function all values constantly change, outside of Card function, values are static, and cards are displayed on top of each other so you can only see one card.

```
const getStyle = () => {
    let angle = Math.random() * 90 - 45
    let xPos = Math.random() * 40 - 20
    let yPos = Math.random() * 40 - 20
    let transform = `translate(${xPos}px, ${yPos}px) rotate(${angle}deg)`
    return transform
}


const Card = (props) => {
    let current = getStyle()
    return (
        <img style={{ transform: current }} className="Card" alt={props.name} src={props.cardImg} />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo).

```js
const Card = (props) => {
    let current = useMemo(getStyle, [])
    return (
        <img style={{ transform: current }} className="Card" alt={props.name} src={props.cardImg} />
    )
}
```

Comment: You just need to import the hook: `import { useMemo } from 'react'` and use it like in my example.